# WCF. Send a message to subscribers asynchronously

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, asynccallback

How do I send subscribers information asynchronously?
RecievMessage-Callback method

```
        public void SendMessage(string message, string name)
        {
            var connection = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IChatClient>();
            string user;
            if (!_users.TryGetValue(connection, out user))
                return;
            foreach (var other in _users.Keys)
            {
                if (other == connection)
                    continue;
                other.RecievMessage(user, message);
            }
        }
```

Without asynchrony, the service cannot cope

Comment: How do I make the SendMessage method asynchronous ?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/synchronous-and-asynchronous-operations) .

Comment: @LanHuang           I can not

Comment: You can use the IAsyncResult asynchronous method to achieve the SendMessage method asynchronous
`[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void SendMessage(byte[] message);`
`public IAsyncResult SendMessage(byte[] message)
{
}`